# harmless snake venom that causes muscle pain?

Tags: science-based, fauna, reptiles, zoology, snake

let say if this snake exist,

it's venomous but it's venom is not dangerous, but it can cause muscle

this snake uses this venom to kill small animals and uses also to make it attackers move slowly because of the muscle cramp when it bites them, giving it a chance to make an escape.

although antivenom is not required

what is the component or venom that this snake can have?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's harmless" and "must be treated"?

Comment: mean the venom is not dangerous to us

Comment: If the venom is "*not considered dangerous to any living thing*" then why does the snake have it? And why is it considered venom in the first place instead of ordinary saliva? Some folks could simply be allergic to the snake saliva.

Comment: Let's clear this up a bit. Pain does not equal harmless. Pain by default causes different reactions to the body. A venom that causes cramping and pain if used in repeated bites would probably amplify those effects to dangerous levels at some point. This venom while "Mild" for snakes is still dangerous. I would expect a venom doing what you described as literally stopping the heart on smaller creatures or causing a painful half-paralysis. I would edit the question to show what the venom is expected to do and maybe the title to ask what can cause these effects.

Comment: @user535733, I think the idea is more that the venom isn't fatal *on its own* (being eaten by the snake while incapacitated is another matter) and has no lasting side effects if the victim isn't injured/killed by something else in the mean time. These are all properties that are desired in an anesthetic, so it doesn't seem implausible for there to exist a substance with these characteristics.

Comment: In what way is this question about creating a fictional world or setting? This question, edited a little for clarity, could easily be asked and answered over on Biology. This is essentially a "real world question without obvious worldbuilding context".

Answer (score 2):

You can take a page from the black widow.  Bites from this spider and others in its family cause a syndrome called **latrodectism**.

[Treatments for Latrodectism—A Systematic Review on Their Clinical Effectiveness](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5408222/)

> However, the most troublesome and predominant feature of systemic
>   latrodectism is local and regional pain, which classically increases
>   over hours. In Australia, local pain radiating up the bitten limb or
>   from the bite site is typical, whereas in North and South America back
>   and abdominal pain predominate [5].The pain is accompanied with
>   nonspecific systemic effects such as nausea, vomiting, headache,
>   malaise and lethargy, local and regional diaphoresis, and less
>   commonly other autonomic neurological effects [5,11].

The venom interferes with receptors on the muscle and causes them to go haywire, causing the cramping and pain.  More on that at linked site if you want it.

Black widows are famous because their bites can kill.  But thousands of people are bitten every year and death is really rare.  People definitely get sick and sore afterwards and many seek medical treatment because they feel so bad.

New England Journal of Medicine describes a case of a 13 year old boy with leg cramps so bad he could not walk, who was back to normal and hour after antivenin (toxin antidote) so if you are looking for something with treatment latrodectism fits the bill here too.

https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199902253400816

> A 13-year-old boy awoke from sleep with a sharp pain on the left side
>   of his neck. He killed a large black spider in the bed. Because of
>   local neck pain and muscle cramps migrating into his chest, abdomen,
>   and legs, he sought care at a nearby hospital... Despite being unable
>   to walk, he was discharged after 24 hours.
>
> The patient sought care at the emergency department of a second
>   hospital three days later. He reported weakness and muscle cramping
>   and was unable to walk... The deep-tendon reflexes were decreased, and
>   he reported tenderness in his neck, abdomen, quadriceps, and distal
>   lower extremities. The patient received one vial of antivenin
>   (Latrodectus mactans) diluted in 100 ml of normal saline and infused
>   over a period of 50 minutes, and 1 liter of normal saline, infused at
>   a separate site. Ten minutes after completion of the infusion, the
>   patient was able to dress himself. Strength in the upper extremities
>   returned to normal, and the patient could walk as well as squat and
>   rise with assistance...

Have your snake produce a venom that works the same way.  A venom that makes the prey cramp up would be reasonable for a snake - it is hard to run away if your legs are totally cramped into knots.  Good defensively as you say - if I got bit by a snake like this and suffered terrible pain for a few days, I would not bother the next one I saw.